# URL routing with parametres causing multiple page loads and retrieving app folders as parametres

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing, system.web.routing

I am implementing URL routing in my asp .net 4.0 application.

I have a hyperlink which redirects to another page with some parameters .

Everything is fine until the first page load,I am able to get the values and page is loaded well ,after that my page is being loaded again and this time I am having my application folder names in RouteData.Values .

Can anyone explain this

In Global asax file My route is as follows

```
       RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("CategoryCodesListView", "CategoryCodesListView/{CatRefID}/{HasSubCat}", "~/CategoryList.aspx");
```

My redirecting Page Code

```
               HyperLink linkItem = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("linkItem");
                RouteValueDictionary parameters =
                                new RouteValueDictionary  
                                 { 
                                    {"CatRefID",RefCodeSysID }, 
                                    { "HasSubCat",lblHasSubCategory.Text } 
                                 };
                VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "CategoryCodesListView", parameters);
                linkItem.NavigateUrl = vpd.VirtualPath;
```

And my recieving page code is 
      string CatRefID= Convert.ToString(Page.RouteData.Values["CatRefID"])

Lets say I passed

```
                CatRefID="Cat1" and  HasSubCat="true";
```

for the first page load I am getting the same values.

but after the page loaded then the page is loading again and now My values are

```
            CatRefID="Scripts" and  HasSubCat="validations.js";
```

Where Scripts is one of folder name in my application and validations.js is a file in it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to **Scripts** folder in your page? If you do, you should correct the address of your scripts that have a link to it. You should use `Ignore` in your `Global.asax` or give an absolute address to your links or upload your scripts and use them as:

```
<script src="http://yourDomain.com/scripts/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ya I have, can you suggest me a way to ignore the scrpt files files in global asax.cs

Comment: I have added  route.RouteExistingFiles = false; to global asax file and that has resolved my multiple page loads. but i am unable to bind the CSS i have tried with adding runat="server" to the links and given them absolute path. still i am not able to bind the CSS to my page .

Comment: Please try this: `<link href="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />` or even `<link href="../../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: can you please look at this and help me [css bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228553/css-bindings-while-using-url-routing)